# react-admin: custom user filters at list component

Tags: admin-on-rest, react-admin

My backend work with filters is like this (for example) :

```
filters = {
  "groupOp": "AND",
  "rules": [
    {
      "field": "id",
      "op": "equal",
      "data": 6
    },
    {
      "field": "partnerId",
      "op": "equal",
      "data": 446
    }
  ],
  "groups": [
    {
      "groupOp": "AND",
      "rules": [
        {
          "field": "username",
          "op": "startswith",
          "data": "Alex"
        }
      ],
      "groups": []
    }
  ]
}
```

It's working fine with persistence filters, but it's not working with user filters that are passed to the list component. For example:

```
export const OrdersFilter = (props) => (
<Filter {...props}>
    <TextInput label="username" source="username" />
    <TextInput label="partnerId" source="partnerId" />
</Filter>
);
```

Because it is a key-value filter and I can't understand how I can add additional fields to the user filter field.

Or how I can wrap url changes ('@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE') after action @@redux-form/CHANGE  to modify the original filter which is passed to the url with the  filtred field name :

```
filter=%7B%22partnerId%22%3A%226%22%7D&order=DESC&page=1&perPage=10'
to 
filter={"field": "partnerId","op": "equal","data": 6}&order=DESC&page=1&perPage=10
```

Answer (score 4):

You should simplify (flatten) the client side filters for `react-admin` and "translate" them in the shape expected by your backend in your `dataProvider`

Comment: i think , it looks useless, because i`d like to allow user to apply filters like one rule from this filter ( https://lefortov.github.io/react-two-way-querybuilder/ ) and i hope i can change default list filters to new one like in example. 
Because sometimes there is a need to search by some field with "like (sql)" condition and sometimes by equals condition

Comment: Nothing prevent you to build a custom Filter component by yourself and pass it to the List component. Look at the source of the default `Filter` component (https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/list/Filter.js). In a nutshell it will be passed a `setFilters` prop allowing you to do whatever you want

Comment: You could also create multiple filters for each possibility and make the translation for your backend in your dataProvider

Comment: thank you, i built custom filter element and it worked fine

Comment: @AlekseyVlasov Can you please show your solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can choose a custom attribute in the filter and through the backend you can apply the filter.

```
const UserFilter = (props) => (
    <Filter {...props}>
        <TextInput label="Username" source="q" alwaysOn />
    </Filter>
);
```

Backend: Loopback4 for example:

```
 async find(@param.filter(User) filter?: Filter<User>): Promise<User[]> {
    if(filter && filter.where){
        const where = filter.where as any;
        if(where["q"]){
          where.username = { ilike: '%'+where["q"]+'%' };
          filter.where = where;
        }
    }
    const response = await this.userRepository.find(filter);
    this.response.set("X-Total-Count", ""+response.length);
    this.response.set("access-control-expose-headers", "X-Total-Count");
    return response;
  }
```